# Make AdminLTE Side Menu stay open when Clicked on

Tags: html, css, adminlte

I am working on a project where I am using AdminLTE as my page template. For the side menu I have it set to be collapsed by default and as the user hovers over each icon the sub menus below will display.

For one section I have a nested menu and when the user clicks on of the menu items to drill down I want the hover menu to stay open even if they scroll off the menu block.

Example of my menu: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dBevvR

So when a user clicks on level 2 under level 1 I want the menu to stay open even when the user hovers off the block.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>AdminLTE 2 | Dashboard</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini sidebar-collapse">
<div class="wrapper">

  <header class="main-header">

    <!-- Logo -->
    <a href="index2.html" class="logo">
      <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
      <span class="logo-mini"><b>A</b>LT</span>
      <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
      <span class="logo-lg"><b>Admin</b>LTE</span>
    </a>

        <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
      <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
      <!--<a id="topMenuIcon" class="sidebar-toggle fa-arrow-right" data-toggle="push-menu" role="button" onclick="changeIcon()">-->
      <a id="topMenuIcon" class="sidebar-toggle fa fa-bars" data-toggle="push-menu" role="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      </a>
    </nav>

  </header> 
  <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
  <aside class="main-sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel -->

      <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
      <ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
        <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>

        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-share"></i> <span>Multilevel</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level One</a></li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level One
                <span class="pull-right-container">
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Two</a></li>
                <li class="treeview">
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Two
                    <span class="pull-right-container">
                      <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                    </span>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Three</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Three</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level One</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->

  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery 3 -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<!-- Sparkline -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery-sparkline/dist/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<!-- jvectormap  -->
<script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
<!-- SlimScroll -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- ChartJS -->
<script src="bower_components/Chart.js/Chart.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="dist/js/demo.js"></script>
</body>

<!--Finish no more change-->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var params = window.location.pathname;
        params = params.toLowerCase();
 
        if (params != "/") {
            $(".nav-sidebar li a").each(function (i) {
                var obj = this;
                var url = $(this).attr("href");
                if (url == "" || url == "#") {
                    return true;
                }
                url = url.toLowerCase();
                if (url.indexOf(params) > -1) {
                    $(this).parent().addClass("active open menu-open");
                    $(this).parent().parent().addClass("active open menu-open");
                    $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass("active open menu-open");
                    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().addClass("active open menu-open");
                    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().addClass("active open menu-open");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Add this script to your sidebar page, then it will work.